# Не сохраняются cookie после закрытия браузера

Tags: javascript, cookie

Необходимо отображать форму на сайте только при первом посещении.
Использую cookie, создаю через js, но почему-то значение cookie уничтожается при закрытии браузера (проверено на chrome, safari).
Код функции установки cookie:

```
function setCookie(cname,val){
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (365*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + val + "; " + expires + "; path=/";

}
```

код функции чтения значения cookie:

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
```

У меня не работает, не могу найти причину. Не уверена, но вроде как пару дней отработало нормально. А сейчас cookie создается, пока браузер не закроешь, значение хранится, как только браузер закроешь, значение удаляется.

То есть как будто "expires" не устанавливается. Как этот параметр можно проверить? Вывожу все cookie в консоль, параметры не отображаются (или их не удалось установить?).

По загрузке страницы считываю cookie, если значение не установлено, то отображаю форму:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        var cookieFormGetGift = getCookie("getgift");
        if (cookieFormGetGift !== "hide") {
            getGiftShow(); //отображение формы
        }
        ...
    }
```

Функция отображения формы:

```
function getGiftShow(){
        setCookie("getgift","hide");
        $('#get-gift-form').show();
}
```

Если нет вариантов решения этой проблемы, предложите, пожалуйста, альтернативный вариант решения задачи, если таковой имеется.

Для браузера chrome вопрос снимается, так как оказалось что в одном из многочисленных скриптов на сайте оказалась функция setCookie(), переименовала функцию – работает. 
Но в safari всё равно не сохраняется параметр expires, и через функцию setCookie() и если жестко указать, вот таким образом:

```
        document.cookie  = "getgift=hide; expires=Fri, 19 Jan 2030 23:59:59 GMT; domain=.mydomain.by"; //здесь вместо mydomain.by стоит имя реального домена
```

Comment: split(';') сразу с пробелом проще.

Comment: проверил, работает, firefox latest

Comment: напишите полный код как вы используете эти функции.

Comment: Неужели никто не сталкивался с подобной проблемой? Может быть через php установка какого-нибудь параметра, который запрещает сохранять параметр expires? Даже не представляю в какую сторону копать.

Answer (score 1):

Проверил ваши скрипты в хроме и фаерфоксе под линуксом. Всё работает. Может у вас системные часы сбились?